# Why am I barely able to read the voltage changes with this circuit?

Tags: analog, sensor, instrumentation, biopotential

I'm using [this EMG sensor](https://www.seeedstudio.com/grove-emg-detector-p-1737.html) to measure the EMG signal from my bicep. However, I can barely read the voltage change from an oscilloscope when my muscle contracts - the output is a horizontal line of 1.5V - a virtual ground because of the use of single supply (I have adjusted the scale, the voltage change is only about 20mV read with an ADC on Arduino when my muscle contracts, I cannot even believe it is caused by my muscle). I'm expecting to see something like the figure below - with a 0.4V amplitude or so (Figure from: [Surface EMG Signal Amplification and Filtering](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Liqiong-Tang/publication/260845647_Surface_EMG_Signal_Amplification_and_Filtering/links/576864d008aef9750b0f9f19/Surface-EMG-Signal-Amplification-and-Filtering.pdf))

[image: Expected output waveform]

The schematic of the sensor is shown as below (also available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeeedDocument/Grove-EMG_Detector/master/res/Grove-EMG_Sensor_v1.1_SCH.pdf)):

[image: schematic]

### My understanding of this circuit:

\$V_{REF}\$ is regulated to 1.5V using the shunt voltage regulator in the bottom left corner. I don't quite understand how the first stage works, especially the function of R5, R12 and C3 (see the Update at the end of this question). C1 and C4 seem to be 2 bypass cap. The second stage is an instrumentation amplifier with an integrator feeding to the reference terminal (works as a high pass filter with cutoff frequency being \$\frac{1}{2\pi R8 C8} \$=1.6Hz). It is quite typical and there is a little mistake in the explanation text - the gain should be \$ 5 \cdot (\frac{R3}{R2})\$ - in this case is 10. The third stage is a passive 1st order high pass filter. I'm not sure why there is a high pass again after the integrator in the previous stage. The fourth stage is a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of \$ 1 + \frac{R1}{R9}\ = 101\$

### My confusion:

I'm so confused why I can barely see voltage changes with the total 1010x gain. The funny thing is when the electrodes are off, I can see the output swings between 0V and VCC - the noise generates larger signal than my muscle does. But when the electrodes are attached, the output is a quiet horizontal line. I attached the electrode connected to the sleeve (in 3.5mm jack) to my elbow. The other 2 electrodes to my bicep (the distance is about 5cm).

First of all I have doubts about the quality of the cable. The EMG cable for this sensor looks to be of poor quality and I guess it is not shielded. I have ordered a shielded one and will test again with the new cable. But is it because the quality of the cable? What is expected to happen with a poor quality cable? I think the output should be swinging if the noise is coupled to the cable.

Second, the design doesn't have the Driven Right Leg (DRL) feedback, which means the common-mode rejection ratio may not be so high. However, the output should also be noisy with the 1010x gain in this case, doesn't it? I'm so confused..

### Update:

R5 and R12 are used to provide the DC bias for the instrumentation amp, as Finbarr said in the comment. The model used for simulation is shown as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Final Update:

1. I tested the circuit and found the gain at 50Hz is only about 20, which is far less than 1000 as designed in the schematic. Maybe that is why I can barely see the voltage changes. I also tried with AC coupling the scope probe, and I could see the voltage change with a scale of 10mV/Div.
2. R5 and R12 do not appear on the actual board. I was thinking that this leads to the small gain because the inputs are not properly biased. Then I found that the circuit only has a gain of 20 with
   properly biased inputs. And then I realised that R5 and R12 are not really needed - the reference electrode which is connected to VREF has already done the work of DC bias.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137997/discussion-on-question-by-george-guo-why-am-i-barely-able-to-read-the-voltage-ch).